# How to convert array tensor to one_hot with specific index?

Tags: tensorflow

```
a = tf.constant([20, 1, 5, 3, 123, 4])
```

I'd like to convert this to `tensor([0,0,0,1,0,0,0])` (index = 3)

How can I easily do this?

What I really tried to do is like this: There is a Deep neural network that has 5 outputs nodes (for classification). Let say the output of one feedforward propagation is [5, 22, 3, 4, 11] (type `tensor`). In this feedforward, the label is 1. So, I need to turn on the value of this index and turn off others like this : [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]. Finally, need to change the value to 1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0] and backpropagate(gradient) this tensor in network.

Comment: I don't clearly understand, `a` is only defines size of output array? and `index_number` is `Tensor` with 0 dimensions?

Comment: @VladimirBystricky I edited post.

Comment: If you want good answers, give us more examples. Right now your problem is not well defined.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I edited it !

Comment: More example inputs & outputs please. Still not clear what you want. Is it just that 0 should give `[1,0,0,0,0]` (which BTW contradicts your second example), 1 should give `[0,1,0,0,0]`, 2 should give `[0,0,1,0,0]`, etc.? i.e. a tensor filled with zeroes except a 1 at the index specified?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett label is from 1 to 5. It doesn't matter much, you can do with 0 to 4 whatever. Important thing is to make whole this process be able to took gradient.

Comment: So your first example is wrong? Please help dispel the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is not one-hot encoding. Maybe this is what you want to achieve:

```
a = tf.constant([20, 1, 5, 3, 123, 4])
c = tf.cast(tf.equal(a, 3), tf.int32)    # 3 is your matching element
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(c.eval())

# [0 0 0 1 0 0]
```

**EDIT**

If you have knowledge about index already, you can do this in multiple ways.
If there is a chance that values in your tensor can repeat, you can do something like this:

```
a = tf.constant([20, 1, 5, 3, 123, 4, 3])
c = tf.cast(tf.equal(a, a[3]), tf.int32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(c.eval())
# [0 0 0 1 0 0 1]
```

But if you are sure that values are not repeated, you can construct this tensor with help of numpy array like this:

```
import numpy as np

c = np.zeros((7), np.int32)
c[3] = 1
c_tensor = tf.constant(c)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(c_tensor.eval())
# [0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
```

**EDIT 2**

Based on newly edited question, for doing a classification task and since it appears to me that you are not doing custom backpropogation, let me give you a skeleton code of the part which you are looking for.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 224, 224, 3))
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None))
one_hot_y = tf.one_hot(y, n_outputs)   # Generate one-hot vector

logits = My_Network(X)   # This function returns your network.
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, one_hot_y)) 
  # This function will compute softmax and get the loss function which you
  # would like to minimize.

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = 0.01).minimize(cross_entropy)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for **each epoch**:
       for **generate batches of your data**:
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict = {X: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

Please spend some time to understand the code. I would also recommend you to follow some tutorial on classification tasks as they are plentily available. I would suggest you [CNN by TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/deep_cnn).

Comment: What if I don't know the value, but only have a knowledge about index?

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: But what I really tried to do is like this: There is a Deep neural network that has 5 ouputs nodes(for classification). Let say the output of one feedfoward propagation is [5, 22, 3, 4, 11] (type `tensor`). In this feedforward, the label is 1. So, I need to turn on the value of this index and turn off others like this : [5, 0, 0, 0, 0]. Finally, need to change the value to 1: [1, 0, 0, 0, 0] and backpropagate(gradient) this tensor in network.

I have followed your first code in edited part but it didn't work well. I think that gradient of `cast` or `equal` doesn't work properly?

Comment: @user3595632, are you writing your own custom backpropogation methodology and not training using the standard `tf.train` methodology? If you are using in-built optimizers like `SGD, Adam` etc, it will not backpropagate as `tf.equal, tf.cast` are non-differentiable functions. Would you be ok if I show you to do what you want with `Softmax` functions?

Comment: Im using ‘tf.gradient’ to calculate the gradient. With softmax, will it break the rule, “output format should be One-hot”?

Comment: @user3595632, I have edited my answer and given a rough code which will help you. Take a look at it. I would suggest you not to use `tf.gradient`, if you just wish to perform classification task  only.

Comment: Sorry but this is what I want:
Looking for a tensorflow `DIFFERENTIABLE` operation to convert CNN raw outputs(right before applied softmax activation and k= 10) to one-hot tensor(using a specific index) when the input is a single unit(SGD).
I meant I'm looking for a tf operation for converting Tensor([10, 11, 5, 2, 1] => Tensor([0, 0, 1, 0, 0,]) (in this case, I set index as 2).
The reason of `DIFFERENTIABLE` operation is that I have to take the gradient of this result one-hot tensor and backprop to the network.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should do it. It uses Numpy:

```
import numpy as np
def one_hot(y):
  y = y.reshape(len(y))
  n_values = int(np.max(y)) + 1
  return tf.convert_to_tensor(np.eye(n_values)[np.array(y, dtype=np.int32)])
```

I am not exactly sure if this what you need, but I hope it helps. 
Example:

```
>>> print(one_hot(np.array([2,3,4])))
>>> [[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
     [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
     [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```